# Link models to users in seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating seed data and I can't figure out how to link the user's email to the auction model in the seller attribute on the seeds page, and I can't figure out how to link the user to the review seed data.

```
seeds.rb

u1 = User.create!(
    name: 'Alice Johnson',
    email: 'alice@email.com',
    password: 'password',
    rating: '3',
    location: 'Memphis, TN'
)

u2 = User.create!(
    name: 'Bob Jones',
    email: 'bob@email.com',
    password: 'password',
    rating: '4',
    location: 'Nashville, TN'

)
a2 = Auction.create!(
    seller: , #Help
    auction_start_time: DateTime.strptime("4/23/2020 08:00", "%m/%d/%Y %R"),
    auction_end_time: DateTime.strptime("5/1/2020 11:59", "%m/%d/%Y %R"),
    category: "Home",
    current_price: 70.0,
    highest_bid: 100.0,
    highest_bidder: "John Doe",
    name: "Vacuum",
    active: TRUE
)

r1 = Review.create!(
    user:u2,
    description: 'The best',
    rating:5,
    reviewer: 'bob@email.com',
    title:'Great',
    user_reviewed:'Alice Johnson'
)
```

```
db/migration/addUSerFkColToReviews

class AddUserFkColToReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :reviews, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to update your question with all the model mentioned in seed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to use `seller: user` you have to have this association in your `Auction` model like this:

`belongs_to :seller, calss_name: 'User'`

Also note you have to make sure that the `seller_id` column is present in your `auctions` table.